# Constructing database using eclipse android sqlite

Tags: android, eclipse

The code is for the registation table for finace app 
The user registers into the app and it is stored into the database 
later it will used to login into app 
my problem is here that the database is being created but the table is not getting created and the appication is closing if we click on the submit button 
similarly with the reset button

actually i should enter the data into the table but

```
public class Register extends Activity  {
        String str1;
     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.register);
```

button for going back to the login page

```
            Button bk=(Button)findViewById(R.id.back);

            bk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent intent1=new Intent(v.getContext(), PersonelFinaceAppActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent1, 0);

                }
            });
```

button for the reset button it resets all the fields

```
            Button rst=(Button)findViewById(R.id.reset);
            rst.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.fn);
                    et.setText("");
                    et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ln);
                    et.setText("");
                    et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.un);
                    et.setText("");
                    et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);
                    et.setText("");
                    et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.monincome);
                    et.setText("");
                    TextView tv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    tv.setText("Firstname ");
                    tv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                    tv.setText("Lastname");
                    tv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                    tv.setText("Username");
                    tv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);
                    tv.setText("Password");
                    tv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView7);
                    tv.setText("Monthlyincome");
                }
            });
```

check button for checking the useralready exits in the database of not

```
            Button chk=(Button)findViewById(R.id.chk);
            chk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        String User;
                        EditText Username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.un);
                        User = Username.getEditableText().toString().trim();
                        SQLiteDatabase db1;
                        db1 = openOrCreateDatabase("Userdetails.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
                        db1.setVersion(3);
                        db1.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
                        db1.setLockingEnabled(true);
                    try{Cursor c1=db1.rawQuery("select Username from details1 where Username='"+User+"'",null);
                                if(c1.moveToNext()){showDialog(1);}
                                else{showDialog(2);}
                            }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO: handle exception
                            }
                        }
                });
```

the problem arises here the submit button 
it has to perform all the action of the app

```
            Button sub=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
            sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)  {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        String First;
                        String Last;
                        String User;
                        String Pass;
                        String monthincome;
                        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                        long l;
                        EditText Firstname =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.fn);
                        EditText Lastname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ln);
                        EditText Username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.un);
                        EditText Password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);
                        EditText moninc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.monincome);
                        First = Firstname.getEditableText().toString().trim();
                        Last = Lastname.getEditableText().toString().trim();
                        Pass = Password.getEditableText().toString().trim();
                        User = Username.getEditableText().toString().trim();
                        monthincome = moninc.getEditableText().toString().trim();
                        if(Firstname.length()<1 || Lastname.length()<1 || Password.length()<1 || Username.length()<1 || moninc.length()<1)
                        {showDialog(3);}
                        else{SQLiteDatabase db1;
                                    db1 = openOrCreateDatabase("Userdetails.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
                                    db1.setVersion(3);
                                    db1.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
                                    db1.setLockingEnabled(true);
                                    final String CREATE_TABLE_DETAILS ="CREATE TABLE details1 (" + "Username INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ," + "Firstname TEXT," + "Lastname TEXT," + "Password TEXT," + "Monthlyincome TEXT);"; 
                            db1.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_DETAILS); 
                            try{Cursor c1=db1.rawQuery("select Username from details1 where Username='"+User+"'",null);
                                        if(c1.moveToNext())
                                        {showDialog(4);}
                                        else{
                                        ContentValues values1 = new ContentValues();
                                        values1.put("Firstname", First);
                                        values1.put("Lastname", Last);
                                        values1.put("Username", User);
                                        values1.put("Password", Pass);
                                        values1.put("Monthlyincome", monthincome);
                                        db1.insert("details1", null, values1);
                                        showDialog(5);
                                        }
                                        }
                                        catch(Exception e)
                                        {}
                                        finally
                                        {}
                        }
                    }
            });
     }

}
```

need help in only the submit button plz help

Comment: can u tell me whats the actual problem..

Comment: the tabel is not geting created and application is getting exit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out the table creation is changed and its done

SQLiteDatabase db1;

db1 = openOrCreateDatabase("Userdetails.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);

db1.setVersion(3);
                             db1.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());

db1.setLockingEnabled(true);

final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS details1 ("+ "ID INTEGER primary key AUTOINCREMENT,"+ "Firstname TEXT,"+ "Lastname TEXT,"+ "Username TEXT,"+ "Password TEXT," + "Monthlyincome TEXT);";

db1.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

Answer (score 0):

```
I think that u should try this

SQLiteDatabase myDB= null;
          String TableName = "db_entry";

          /* Create a Database. */
          try {
           myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("db_hw3", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
           myDB.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS db_entry" );
           /* Create a Table in the Database. */
           myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
             + TableName
             + " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, mb_text TEXT NOT NULL,ph_location TEXT);");

          }
          catch(Exception e) {
           Log.e("Error", "Error", e);
          }
```

Comment: no its not coming when i exegute it the database is not being created